# OBD Mode 07 Multi-Frame

Tags: tcp, packet, obd-ii, elm327

I am trying to parse the message coming from an OBD device for Mode 07, and I am having a tough time with it.  The following is the response I get from the device.

`00 10 08 10 0A 47 04 01 07 02 07 00 10 08 21 03 07 43 07 00 00 00 00 18 06 47 02 01 02 D6 00 00 28 04 47 01 A2 45`

Could someone please help clarify the different bytes? Ideally, I would like to identify that the response is multi-frame and how to identify the begin/end of the packet.

Answer (score 0):

It shows the standard [OBD-II PIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#Mode_01) as defined by SAE J1979. The expected response for each PID(hex) is given, along with information on how to translate the response into meaningful data.

Eg.

> When using Bit-Encoded-Notation, quantities like **D6** means bit **6** from data byte **D**. Each bit is numerated from *0 to 7*, so **7** is the most significant bit and **0** is the least significant bit.

Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs